Column divider breaks using multirow
I am trying to compile a table where the last column takes two rows, but when the table complies the rightmost column divider has a break over the second row, any help would be appreciated!
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|}
        \hline
        k & h (sec) & Error & $\log \left( \frac{E_h}{E_{h/10}} \right)$ \\ \hline
        2.5 \times 10^{-2} & 1.0 & 1.2227 \times 10^{-9} & \multirow{2}{*}{3.9992} \\ 
        2.5 \times 10^{-2} & 0.1 & 1.2251 \times 10^{-13} \\ \hline
        a & b & c & d
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a "Minimal Working Example" (MWE) that starts with \documentclass, includes all relevant \usepackage commands, ends with \end{document} and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

You need to “close” all rows and you're missing an & in the one that lacks the rule.
Your document doesn't compile, of course, because you're missing math mode.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|}
        \hline
        k & h (sec) & Error & $\log \left( \frac{E_h}{E_{h/10}} \right)$ \\ \hline
        $2.5 \times 10^{-2}$ & 1.0 & $1.2227 \times 10^{-9}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{3.9992} \\ 
        $2.5 \times 10^{-2}$ & 0.1 & $1.2251 \times 10^{-13}$ & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}


However, note that the symbol for second is “s”.
Here's a different realization. Note the alignment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.1e-1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.4e-2]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$k$} & {$h$ (\unit{s})} & {Error} & {$\log \left( \frac{E_h}{E_{h/10}} \right)$} \\
\midrule
2.5e-2 & 1.0 & 1.2227e-9 & 3.9992 \\
2.5e-2 & 0.1 & 1.2251e-13 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


You might use \multirow for the last column, but it's not really needed and a blank is interpreted as “repeat the above value”.
